# Batch file to arrange files per name into relevant folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following folders:

```
Apple_folder
Pear_folder
Tomatoes_folder
```

Within `Apple_folder`, I have the following files:

```
Extracted-Apple_1.txt
Extracted-Apple_2.txt
Extracted-Pear_1.txt
Extracted-Pear_2.txt
Extracted-Apple_3.txt
Extracted-Tomatoes_1.txt
```

How do I move `Extracted-Pear_1.txt`, `Extracted-Pear_2.txt`, `Extracted-Tomatoes_1.txt` into their relevant folders, i.e. keep file name that contain `apple` under `Apple_folder`, etc.

Expected `Apple_folder` contents:

```
Extracted-Apple_1.txt
Extracted-Apple_2.txt
Extracted-Apple_3.txt
```

Expected `Pear_folder` contents:

```
Extracted-Pear_1.txt
Extracted-Pear_2.txt
```

Expected `Tomatoes_folder` contents:

```
Extracted-Tomatoes_1.txt
```

I am still a beginner in batch script, so not sure how to proceed?

The following script didn't work.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A counter=0

@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=-_" %%f in ("%%a") do (
        set /A counter+=1 
        MOVE "%%a" "C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\%%f_folder\Extracted-%%~nf_moved__!counter!.txt"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: If I assume, _since you've not provided us with sufficient information_, that your running batch script is located in `C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script`, then your script should read `Apple_folder\*.txt` instead of `*.txt` and the first instance of `"%%a"` should be `"%%~na"`.

Comment: That's correct but, I would like the script to be able to check all folders under Batch_script and move files into relevant folders if needed (as most of the files would be under the correct folder).

Comment: Nbl123, that's another question. Please try something yourself based upon what you learn from reading the output from `for /?` and /or `dir /?`, and from researching similar questions already on this site. If once you've written and tested it, and it exhibits a specific issue, you may have sufficient reason to post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this. This is the solution I was looking for. It will recognise the file names and check whether they're under the right folder, if not it will move them under the right folder:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /R "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\" %%G IN (*.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=7,12,13 delims=\-_." %%a in ("!%%G!") do (
            set /A counter+=1 
IF NOT %%a==%%b (MOVE "%%G" "C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\%%b_folder\MSG-Extracted-%%b_%%c_moved_!counter!.txt")
    )
)
```